# How do I run Rails in Docker? PG::ConnectionBad could not translate host name "pg" to address: No address associated with hostname

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I tried to follow the guide here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  pg:                                     ######### LOOK HERE!
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails server -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - pg
    links:
      - pg                                     ######### LOOK HERE!
  cms:
    image: joomla
    restart: always
    links:
      - mysql:joomladb
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      JOOMLA_DB_HOST: mysql
      JOOMLA_DB_PASSWORD: example
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
```

`config/database.yml`

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  host: pg                                     ######### LOOK HERE!
  username: postgres
  password:

development:
  <<: *default
  database: project

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: project_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: project
```

Console

```
C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\project\src>docker-compose run web rake db:create
Starting src_pg_1 ... done
could not translate host name "pg" to address: No address associated with hostname
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000, "host"=>"pg", "username"=>"postgres", "password"=>nil, "database"=>"project"}
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not translate host name "pg" to address: No address associated with hostname
```

docker-compose version 1.20.1, build 5d8c71b2, Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24302

Comment: did you managed to solve this?

Comment: @wilgosz.pl No! I'm glad I'm not the only one who has a problem and realizes Docker is a piece of crap. It had so much potential, but if it can't resolve hostnames then it is of no use,

Comment: Chloe, Please check my answer. When I try to run: `docker-compose up web`, the `pg` issue is there, but when I run it without the `web`, it tries to run all services and then the `depend_on` catches up. 

So either: 
1. run it in one terminal session: `docker-compose up` 
2. then run: `docker-compose run web rake db:create`

Will it help?

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I'll try to answer this:

Usually when this error appears, it probably means that running the `db` container returned some errors and it stopped.

I had the same issue and after some digging found that I had

```
LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
LANGUAGE='en_US:en'
LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'
```

set in my environment variable and that caused the `db` container to stop. Therefore as the container was not running, I had no `db` host.

Here is how my `docker-compose.yml` file looks like:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file: .env
  app:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec puma -p 3000 -C config/puma.rb
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3031:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Here is `config/database.yml`

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: db
  pool: 5
  username: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_PASSWORD'] %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: driggl_dev

test:
  <<: *default
  database: driggl_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: driggl_prod
```

...and the `.env` file for development:

```
POSTGRES_USER=driggl
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=driggl
```

As I had shared volumes for db data, I removed the `tmp/db` folder from the repository just to be sure.

```
rm -rf tmp/*
```

then I removed all containers and images

```
docker rm $(docker ps -q -a) -f
docker rmi $(docker images -q) -f
```

Finally I spin up containers again:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

and everything finally went right.

**Summary**

1. Make sure there is nothing cached somewhere in the system
2. Make sure your db container does not return errors while launching.

I hope that will help anyone who'll encounter that problem.

Comment: There must be a way to do this without combining the containers in one compose file, and building them together.  Docker has its own network - how to address to it in the database.yml file?

Comment: This answer saved my day.

Answer (score 4):

This setup works for me running rails on docker. Basically need to specify a URL so you'll use a .env file to specify the postgres url and you'll change between _development _test and _production using your config/database file just make you add the env. file to your web service docker-compose file:

/docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: kunzig #DockerHub postgres docs state this is optional but must be used when password is set.  It will also create a db under the supplied username which you'll use to connect to in rails console such as: $docker-compose exec postgres psql -U YourUserNameHere
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'whateverPWYouWant'
    ports:
      - '5432' #Was originally 5432:5432 with the Left hand side being port on host machine, right hand side is the port on the docker container.  However I let docker choose the port it will use by supplying because 5432 is running on my local for other projects.  
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data 



  web:
    build: . #Runs the docker build command on the current directory
    links: #Links the listed services to our application so containers can talk to eachother
      - postgres
      - redis
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/kunzig #Left hand side is current directory of compose file, right hand side is container folder.  This needs to be same as Install_path folder in Dockerfile.
    ports:
      - '8000:8000' #Left is the local port and the right side is the container port
    env_file:
      - .YourProjectNameHere.env #This should be in your root project directory along side the Dockerfile and docker-compose file
    depends_on:
      - 'redis'
      - 'postgres'
```

/.projectname.env

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://PostgresUserNameHere:PasswordFromDockerCompose@postgres:5432/PostgresUsername?encoding=utf8&pool=5&timeout=5000
```

/config/database.yml

```
development:
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'].gsub('?', '_development?' ) %>
test:
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'].gsub('?', '_test?' ) %>
production:
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'].gsub('?', '_production?' ) %>
```

Keep your web service linked with the pg service as you have it and you should be good to go just note I called my service postgres instead.

Comment: But you still use the hostname `@postgres:5432` so if it can't find the hostname now, how will it by using a URL containing the hostname?

Answer (score 1):

Just adding as this this the first hit when googling this issue.

Similar (but different) to the answer from @swilgosz - my db was failing to launch with a:

```
could not write lock file "postmaster.pid": No space left on device
```

Sure enough after running a quick:

```
docker system prune
```

Everything worked again. Pretty obvious in retrospect but thought I'd add this in case it saves anyone time.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. For the life of me I could not figure out why it was happening. Debugged for quite a while, but could not figure out how to make the `container_name` for the db container resolve within my `database.yml` file. Even weirder was the fact that in a different computer the same configuration was working totally fine.

Eventually I found out that if you use `host.docker.internal` it is essentially the equivalent of `localhost` within Docker.

So I changed my `database.yml` file to be:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: host.docker.internal
  port: 5432
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

And it all worked out. Mind you I have heard this does not work in Unix systems. I am using OS X and this works fine.