# Unable to resolve hostname with docker-compose and podman

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hostname, podman, mastodon

I am trying to deploy a mastodon server using this project: https://github.com/tootsuite/mastodon

I am running Docker-Compose and Podman on a Fedora 33 server.

```
$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.27.4, build unknown

$ docker --version
podman version 3.0.1

$ cat /etc/fedora-release
Fedora release 33 (Thirty Three)
```

I had to do some changes into the docker-compose.yml to make it work with Podman. You can see my whole config file below.

```
version: '3'
services:

  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    shm_size: 256mb
    networks:
      - internal_network
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "postgres"]
      timeout: 45s
      interval: 10s
      retries: 10
    volumes:
      - ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust

  redis:
    restart: always
    image: redis:6.0-alpine
    networks:
      - internal_network
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      timeout: 45s
      interval: 10s
      retries: 10
    volumes:
      - ./redis:/data

#  es:
#    restart: always
#    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.8.10
#    environment:
#      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
#      - "cluster.name=es-mastodon"
#      - "discovery.type=single-node"
#      - "bootstrap.memory_lock=true"
#    networks:
#      - internal_network
#    healthcheck:
#      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl --silent --fail localhost:9200/_cluster/health || exit 1"]
#    volumes:
#      - ./elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
#    ulimits:
#      memlock:
#        soft: -1
#        hard: -1

  web:
    #    build: .
    image: tootsuite/mastodon
    restart: always
    env_file: .env.production
    command: bash -c "rm -f /mastodon/tmp/pids/server.pid; bundle exec rails s -p 3000"
    networks:
      - external_network
      - internal_network
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "wget -q --spider --proxy=off localhost:3000/health || exit 1"]
      timeout: 45s
      interval: 10s
      retries: 10
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
#      - es
    volumes:
      - ./public/system:/mastodon/public/system

  streaming:
    build: .
    image: tootsuite/mastodon
    restart: always
    env_file: .env.production
    command: node ./streaming
    networks:
      - external_network
      - internal_network
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "wget -q --spider --proxy=off localhost:4000/api/v1/streaming/health || exit 1"]
      timeout: 45s
      interval: 10s
      retries: 10
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:4000:4000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis

  sidekiq:
    build: .
    image: tootsuite/mastodon
    restart: always
    env_file: .env.production
    command: bundle exec sidekiq
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    networks:
      - external_network
      - internal_network
    volumes:
      - ./public/system:/mastodon/public/system
## Uncomment to enable federation with tor instances along with adding the following ENV variables
## http_proxy=http://privoxy:8118
## ALLOW_ACCESS_TO_HIDDEN_SERVICE=true
#  tor:
#    image: sirboops/tor
#    networks:
#      - external_network
#      - internal_network
#
#  privoxy:
#    image: sirboops/privoxy
#    volumes:
#      - ./priv-config:/opt/config
#    networks:
#      - external_network
#      - internal_network

networks:
  external_network:
  internal_network:
    internal: true
```

Here is a diff with remote version of the file on the repository:

(tl;dr: I added options to health-checks and an env variable to authorize running postgres without password and commented build option to use image from the repo, as building was failing too)

```
$ git diff docker-compose.yml
diff --git a/docker-compose.yml b/docker-compose.yml
index 52eea7a74..a8e047ec7 100644
--- a/docker-compose.yml
+++ b/docker-compose.yml
@@ -9,8 +9,13 @@ services:
       - internal_network
     healthcheck:
       test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "postgres"]
+      timeout: 45s
+      interval: 10s
+      retries: 10
     volumes:
       - ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
+    environment:
+      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust

   redis:
     restart: always
@@ -19,6 +24,9 @@ services:
       - internal_network
     healthcheck:
       test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
+      timeout: 45s
+      interval: 10s
+      retries: 10
     volumes:
       - ./redis:/data

@@ -42,7 +50,7 @@ services:
 #        hard: -1

   web:
-    build: .
+    #    build: .
     image: tootsuite/mastodon
     restart: always
     env_file: .env.production
@@ -52,6 +60,9 @@ services:
       - internal_network
     healthcheck:
       test: ["CMD-SHELL", "wget -q --spider --proxy=off localhost:3000/health || exit 1"]
+      timeout: 45s
+      interval: 10s
+      retries: 10
     ports:
       - "127.0.0.1:3000:3000"
     depends_on:
@@ -72,6 +83,9 @@ services:
       - internal_network
     healthcheck:
       test: ["CMD-SHELL", "wget -q --spider --proxy=off localhost:4000/api/v1/streaming/health || exit 1"]
+      timeout: 45s
+      interval: 10s
+      retries: 10
     ports:
       - "127.0.0.1:4000:4000"
     depends_on:
```

Generating secrets was fine, but it failed on this command:

```
$ sudo docker-compose run --rm web bundle exec rails db:migrate
Creating network "mastodon_internal_network" with the default driver
Creating network "mastodon_external_network" with the default driver
Creating mastodon_db_1    ... done
Creating mastodon_redis_1 ... done
Creating mastodon_web_run ... done
rails aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known
```

I already used the combination of Docker-Compose and Podman 3.0 with several projects and I never had any issue with hostname resolving inside networks. I wonder if I must specify a driver for this situation.

Also I would like a way to test if I can reach db service with this hostname from the container of web and so, if the problem is in the code (that I highly doubt but I want to be sure).

EDIT1: Logs of db service showing that the service seems to be running fine and ready to accept connections

```
$ sudo docker logs -f mastodon_db_1

PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization

LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-04-01 07:02:04 UTC
LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50090012/how-do-i-run-rails-in-docker-pgconnectionbad-could-not-translate-host-name-p/50090286 helps you, or try to set `hostname` for `db` in `docker-compose`.

Comment: Unfortunately it was not helping.

db service is running fine. (see logs in first post)

and even with hostname or aliases, I got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution: removing networks' definition.

It sounds cheap, but it worked.

So the final `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:

  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    shm_size: 256mb
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "postgres"]
      timeout: 45s
      interval: 10s
      retries: 10
    volumes:
      - ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust

  redis:
    restart: always
    image: redis:6.0-alpine
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      timeout: 45s
      interval: 10s
      retries: 10
    volumes:
      - ./redis:/data

#  es:
#    restart: always
#    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.8.10
#    environment:
#      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
#      - "cluster.name=es-mastodon"
#      - "discovery.type=single-node"
#      - "bootstrap.memory_lock=true"
#    networks:
#      - internal_network
#    healthcheck:
#      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl --silent --fail localhost:9200/_cluster/health || exit 1"]
#    volumes:
#      - ./elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
#    ulimits:
#      memlock:
#        soft: -1
#        hard: -1

  web:
    #    build: .
    image: tootsuite/mastodon
    restart: always
    env_file: .env.production
    command: bash -c "rm -f /mastodon/tmp/pids/server.pid; bundle exec rails s -p 3000"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "wget -q --spider --proxy=off localhost:3000/health || exit 1"]
      timeout: 45s
      interval: 10s
      retries: 10
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
#      - es
    volumes:
      - ./public/system:/mastodon/public/system

  streaming:
    build: .
    image: tootsuite/mastodon
    restart: always
    env_file: .env.production
    command: node ./streaming
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "wget -q --spider --proxy=off localhost:4000/api/v1/streaming/health || exit 1"]
      timeout: 45s
      interval: 10s
      retries: 10
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:4000:4000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis

  sidekiq:
    build: .
    image: tootsuite/mastodon
    restart: always
    env_file: .env.production
    command: bundle exec sidekiq
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    volumes:
      - ./public/system:/mastodon/public/system
## Uncomment to enable federation with tor instances along with adding the following ENV variables
## http_proxy=http://privoxy:8118
## ALLOW_ACCESS_TO_HIDDEN_SERVICE=true
#  tor:
#    image: sirboops/tor
#    networks:
#      - external_network
#      - internal_network
#
#  privoxy:
#    image: sirboops/privoxy
#    volumes:
#      - ./priv-config:/opt/config
#    networks:
#      - external_network
#      - internal_network
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but the cause was different. On my system a required package was not installed.

First check your podman network-backend:

```
$ podman info | grep -i networkbackend
>  networkBackend: cni
```

Depending on the output you might be missing the package `cni-plugin-dnsname` or `aardvark-dns`. In my case `cni-plugin-dnsname` was missing.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it is not a workaround but rather the correct answer.